# Does Fedora's firewall use iptables?

Tags: fedora, iptables

Fedora has a Firewall Configuration interface:

[image: Screenshot of the interface]

Does this use `iptables` underneath to enforce the rules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume it does, but it's easy to find out to make sure:

As root or via sudo do:

`iptables -L` (iptables is usually located under `/sbin`)

It should print out a bunch of rules. If you see rules that match what you selected via the GUI interface, you can assume it does. :)

Comment: Or you can just check out the source to find out for sure.

Answer (score 3):

It pretty much has to, unless they've done a whole lot of reinventing the wheel in order to talk to the kernel's netfilter interface directly, which would mean a great deal of hassle for absolutely no benefit -- there's literally nothing that said interface can do that iptables can't tell it to.

If you want to be sure, go to a root console and type

```
iptables -L
```

You should see a list of active filter rules.